# Fatal Error SQLite3::query() in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I got the following Error while I try to make Forget Password page in PHP using SQLite3

```
Fatal error: Non-static method SQLite3::query() cannot be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\s\sqlite\forgot.php on line 16
```

I am trying to Make Login System in PHP using SQLite3. I have done all correct throughout the login, But Forget Password makes my hair grey :/ Here is my PHP Code for Forget Password. Which is Forget.php

```
<?php 

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('test.db');
  }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db)
{
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else{ }

 $query = SQLite3::query($db, 'SELECT email, password FROM user LIMIT 25');
 $result = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_ASSOC);
 foreach ($result as $entry) {
 echo 'Email: ' . $entry['email'] . '  Password: ' . $entry['password0'];
 }
 ?>



<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Forgot Password</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">
        <h1> Forgot password!</h1>
        <label> Enter Your Email ID : </label>

        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required=" " />

        <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You know what is `static`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should've known why you have created the `$db` object. Use that properly instead of calling `SQLite3::query` statically (which isn't a static function).

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT email, password FROM user LIMIT 25');
```

See the examples here to run query in SQLite3 http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php